# Echo a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested

I have a multidimensional array and I'm trying to find out how to simply "echo" the elements of the array. The depth of the array is not known, so it could be deeply nested.

In the case of the array below, the right order to echo would be:

```
This is a parent comment
This is a child comment
This is the 2nd child comment
This is another parent comment
```

This is the array I was talking about:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [comment_id] => 1
            [comment_content] => This is a parent comment
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [comment_id] => 3
                            [comment_content] => This is a child comment
                            [child] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [comment_id] => 4
                                            [comment_content] => This is the 2nd child comment
                                            [child] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [comment_id] => 2
            [comment_content] => This is another parent comment
            [child] => Array
                (
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: It would depend which order you'd like it to be echo'ed: breadth-first or depth-first?

--Just kidding, you already included the order you wanted

Comment: Are you wanting to echo this for the purposes of display to a user or for the purposes of development checking / debugging the contents of the array?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like you're only trying to write one important value from each array.  Try a recursive function like so:

```
function RecursiveWrite($array) {
    foreach ($array as $vals) {
        echo $vals['comment_content'] . "\n";
        RecursiveWrite($vals['child']);
    }
}
```

You could also make it a little more dynamic and have the `'comment_content'` and `'child'` strings passed into the function as parameters (and continue passing them in the recursive call).

Comment: Isn't it foreach($array as $elem)? :) Nice answer though!

Comment: @eric-gagnon: yep, you just beat me to it.  Fixed.

Answer (score 30):

```
<pre>
<?php print_r ($array); ?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 6):

Proper, Better, and Clean Solution:

```
function traverseArray($array)
{
    // Loops through each element. If element again is array, function is recalled. If not, result is echoed.
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            Self::traverseArray($value); // Or
            // traverseArray($value);
        }
        else
        {
            echo $key . " = " . $value . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
}
```

You simply call in this helper function `traverseArray($array)` in your current/main class like this:

```
$this->traverseArray($dataArray); // Or
// traverseArray($dataArray);
```

source: http://snipplr.com/view/10200/recursively-traverse-a-multidimensional-array/

Comment: Proper, better, and cleaner to check that each value is an array and generic enough to handle any nested arrays.

Answer (score 2):

`print_r($arr)` usually gives pretty readable result.

Answer (score 1):

if you wanted to store it as a variable you could do:

```
recurse_array($values){
    $content = '';
    if( is_array($values) ){
        foreach($values as $key => $value){
            if( is_array($value) ){
                $content.="$key<br />".recurse_array($value);
            }else{
                $content.="$key = $value<br />";
            }

        }
    }
    return $content;
}

$array_text = recurse_array($array);
```

Obviously you can format as needed!

Comment: Good idea on the string capture.  Be wary of concatenation in a loop though.  If the array is of any significant size (or depth), you'll probably be better off with echoes and wrapping the function with `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()`

Answer (score 1):

**There are multiple ways to do that**

1) - `print_r($array);` or if you want nicely formatted array then

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($array); echo '<pre/>';
```

//-------------------------------------------------
2) - use `var_dump($array)` to get more information of the content in the array like datatype and length.
//-------------------------------------------------
3) - you can loop the array using php's `foreach();` and get the desired output.

```
function recursiveFunction($array) {
    foreach ($array as $val) {
            echo $val['comment_content'] . "\n";
            recursiveFunction($vals['child']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're outputting the data for debugging and development purposes, [Krumo](http://krumo.sourceforge.net/) is great for producing easily readable output. Check out the [example output](http://kaloyan.info/krumo/index.php#example).

Answer (score 0):

Recursion would be your answer typically, but an alternative would be to use references. See http://www.ideashower.com/our_solutions/create-a-parent-child-array-structure-in-one-pass/