# Print 2nd array from array of arrays php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array of arrays. e.g

```
$value= array(
   ['global'] => array('1'=>'amar'),
   ['others'] => array('1' => 'johnson')
);
```

My question is how do I print only the second array. I know I can print by using print $value['others'] but my problem here is the other value may change. It may be ['blah1'],
['blah2']. So I need a php line of codes to echo second array print $value['others'] where the others may be different word.

I also my new array should look like this 
$value= array(['others'] => array('1' => 'johnson'));

Thank you

Comment: Try a recursive function like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719326/echo-a-multidimensional-array-in-php

Comment: try print_r($value['others']) ?

Comment: If you don't know the names of your keys in advance, you'll have to figure out what key you want to deal with in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use the array pointer here. (*Note: O(1) complexity, fetching keys/values list first is O(n)*)

```
reset($array); // set pointer to the first element
$your_array = next($array); // fetch next == second element
```

Comment: Thank you very Much btw what if I want $value= array(
   ['others'] => array('1' => 'johnson') only

Comment: how do if i want  $value= array( ['others'] => array('1' => 'johnson') only

Comment: `$your_array["others"] = next($array);` or what do you mean? (replace second line)

Comment: I want new array to be $value=arra('others' => array('1'=>'johnsion')); others should be what ever was there on the original array on second array

Comment: @user1140176 yes `$your_array["others"] = next($array);` is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

*PHP version 5.4 +* :

```
var_dump($value[array_keys($value)[1]]); //get array of keys and access array with the second key
```

***or***

```
var_dump(array_values($value)[1]); // get an indexed array and access the second element
```

*PHP version < 5.4*

```
$keys = array_keys($value); 
var_dump($value[$keys[1]]);
```

***or***

```
$value = array_values($value);
var_dump($value[1]);
```

Comment: Note, this only works in PHP 5.4+.  In older PHP versions, you'd need to do: `$keys = array_keys($value); var_dump($value[$keys[1]]);`.

Comment: Or from the other direction you can discard the keys entirely and do `var_dump(array_values($value)[1])`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the last element:

```
$result = end($array);
```

Or to access by index number:

```
$array = array_values($array);
```