# PHP : echo Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, echo

i have an array output like this :

```
Array
(
    [2015-01-23] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [orgdate] => 2015-01-23
                    [origin] => india
                )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [orgdate] => 2015-01-23
                [origin] => us
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [orgdate] => 2015-01-23
                [origin] => england
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [orgdate] => 2015-01-23
                [origin] => india2
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [orgdate] => 2015-01-23
                [origin] => uae
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [orgdate] => 2015-01-23
                [origin] => africa
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [orgdate] => 2015-01-23
                [origin] => china
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [orgdate] => 2015-01-23
                [origin] => hongkong
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [orgdate] => 2015-01-23
                [origin] => africa2
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [orgdate] => 2015-01-23
                [origin] => africa3
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [orgdate] => 2015-01-23
                [origin] => africa4
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [orgdate] => 2015-01-23
                [origin] => africa5 
            )

    )

[2015-01-14] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [orgdate] => 2015-01-14
                [origin] => japan1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [orgdate] => 2015-01-14
                [origin] => japan2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [orgdate] => 2015-01-14
                [origin] => japan3
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [orgdate] => 2015-01-14
                [origin] => japan4
            )

    )

[2015-01-13] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [orgdate] => 2015-01-13
                [origin] => russia
            )

    )

)
```

now i want to display 2015-01-23 , 2015-01-14 , 2015-01-13 and then each inner contents

```
origin: india
origin: usa
origin: england , etc....
```

how i accomplish this.? i already tried recursive function like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719326/echo-a-multidimensional-array-in-php) , but this couldn't find solution

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: your question is ambiguous..the inner array doesn't have 'origin' key at all how can you expect it to print

Comment: could you please provide an accurate example of the result you want to achieve? it's not very clear...

Comment: i edited the question, please refresh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need a recursion as your array is flat (only 1 deep)

I'm not sure what you want but:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$subarray)
{
    echo $key;
    foreach($array[$key] as $subarray)
    {
        echo "origin".$subarray["origin"];
    }
}
```

this should work.
If you just want to see for debug, use var_dump($array);

Comment: my comment about recursion is wrong though. You need a recursion when you don't know how deep is your array.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
foreach($array as $innerArray){
 foreach($innerArray as $result){
echo "origin: "." ".$result['orgdate']." ".$result['origin'];
 }
}
```