# after sorting the array using array_multisort how to show all the data using loop

Tags: php

Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[hashtag] => a7e87329b5eab8578f4f1098a152d6f4
[title] => Flower
[order] => 3
)

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [hashtag] => b24ce0cd392a5b0b8dedc66c25213594
        [title] => Free
        [order] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [hashtag] => e7d31fc0602fb2ede144d18cdffd816b
        [title] => Ready
        [order] => 1
    )
```

)

Comment: Please show us your best effort (`code`) - your question is unclear, read [ask]!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP : echo Multidimensional Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250234/php-echo-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is correctly assigned to a variable with name `$array`

You can show all the data with `Print_r($array);` or `var_dump($array);`

You can loop through the array keys with:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val)
```

e.g

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {

    echo "<b>Key: ".$key."</b><br/>
    Hashtag: ".$val['hashtag']."<br>
    Title: ".$val['title']."<br/>
    Order: ".$val['order']."<br/><br/>";
}
```

Or you could assign it to a recursive function to print the multidimensional array.