# Extract JSON ouput to get line by line key pair values using PHP

Tags: php, json

I would like to extract JSON ouput using PHP and tried below code but I'm getting output of single character instead of row wise values. I read similar posts but failed to get key pair values and getting output as single character. Wherever field values won't present, null is ok for that. How can I get output line by line for respective keys?

## Tried code:

```
while (!feof($resultFile)) {
    $line = fgets ($resultFile);
    echo $line;
    $someArray = json_decode($line);
    foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {
        echo $value["key"] . ", " . $value["status"] . "<br>";
  }
}
```

## someArray output:

```
Array ( [key] => XYZ-6680 [status] => Open [components] => API [currentVersion] => Release1.2 [expectedVersion] => Array ( ) [customerInfo] => Default Calendar when the delegate responds to those invitations. ) Array ( [key] => XYZ-3325 [status] => Closed [components] => API [currentVersion] => Release 1.0 [expectedVersion] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [self] => https://bug.restify.com/rest/api/2/version/27771 [id] => 27771 [name] => Release1.2 [archived] => [released] => ) ) [customerInfo] => Fixed a number of bugs related to DA: * CrossMailboxSearch: Group label was shown even when all setting items of the group were hidden on New Account dialog ([https://bug.goog.restify/show_bug.cgi?id=1542 Bug 1542]) * After performing a bulk migration, the Delegated Admin user encountered an `HTTP Error 403` when attempting to download the list of provisioned accounts ([https://bug.goog.restify/show_bug.cgi?id=1039 Bug 1039]) ) Array ( [key] => XYZ-223 [status] => Closed [components] => API [currentVersion] => Release 1.3 [expectedVersion] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [self] => https://bug.restify.com/rest/api/2/version/29171 [id] => 29171 [name] => Release1.2 [archived] => [released] => ) ) [customerInfo] => "Default Calendar" user preference, `zimbraPrefDefaultCalendarId`. )
```

## line output:

```
{"key":"XYZ-6680","status":"Open","components":"API","currentVersion":"Release1.2","expectedVersion":[],"customerInfo":"Default Calendar when the delegate responds to those invitations."} X, X
O, O
A, A
R, R
,
D, D
{"key":"XYZ-3325","status":"Closed","components":"API","currentVersion":"Release 1.0","expectedVersion":[{"self":"https://bug.restify.com/rest/api/2/version/27771","id":"27771","name":"Release1.2","archived":false,"released":false}],"customerInfo":"Fixed a number of bugs related to DA: * CrossMailboxSearch: Group label was shown even when all setting items of the group were hidden on New Account dialog ([https://bug.goog.restify/show_bug.cgi?id=1542 Bug 1542]) * After performing a bulk migration, the Delegated Admin user encountered an `HTTP Error 403` when attempting to download the list of provisioned accounts ([https://bug.goog.restify/show_bug.cgi?id=1039 Bug 1039])"} X, X
C, C
A, A
R, R
,
F, F
{"key":"XYZ-223","status":"Closed","components":"API","currentVersion":"Release 1.3","expectedVersion":[{"self":"https://bug.restify.com/rest/api/2/version/29171","id":"29171","name":"Release1.2","archived":false,"released":false}],"customerInfo":"\"Default Calendar\" user preference, `zimbraPrefDefaultCalendarId`."}X, X
C, C
A, A
R, R
,
", "
```

## JSON (resultFile content):

```
{"key":"XYZ-6680","status":"Open","components":"API","currentVersion":"Release1.2","expectedVersion":[],"customerInfo":"Default Calendar when the delegate responds to those invitations."}
{"key":"XYZ-3325","status":"Closed","components":"API","currentVersion":"Release 1.0","expectedVersion":[{"self":"https://bug.restify.com/rest/api/2/version/27771","id":"27771","name":"Release1.2","archived":false,"released":false}],"customerInfo":"Fixed a number of bugs related to DA: * CrossMailboxSearch: Group label was shown even when all setting items of the group were hidden on New Account dialog ([https://bug.goog.restify/show_bug.cgi?id=1542 Bug 1542]) * After performing a bulk migration, the Delegated Admin user encountered an `HTTP Error 403` when attempting to download the list of provisioned accounts ([https://bug.goog.restify/show_bug.cgi?id=1039 Bug 1039])"}
{"key":"XYZ-223","status":"Closed","components":"API","currentVersion":"Release 1.3","expectedVersion":[{"self":"https://bug.restify.com/rest/api/2/version/29171","id":"29171","name":"Release1.2","archived":false,"released":false}],"customerInfo":"\"Default Calendar\" user preference, `zimbraPrefDefaultCalendarId`."}
```

## Expected output:

Line by line values of key, status, components, currentVersion, expectedVersion, customerInfo.

## Actual output:

[image: Output]

Comment: I see you have a line of code that says "echo $line" where are the results of that ?

Comment: Added line output too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, @Curious_mind is right about forcing output of json_decode as an associative array with second parameter to true.  Then I think you should get what you want by echoing directly $key and $value, like so:

```
while (!feof($resultFile)) {
    $line = fgets ($resultFile);
    echo $line;
    $someArray = json_decode($line,true); 
    foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {
        echo key . ", " . $value . "<br/>";
  }
}
```

BUT, careful, if $value is an array, you will get an error (can't just echo an array), so you need to handle the array resulting of you json recusivly.

I adapt the function found here: [Echo a multidimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719326/echo-a-multidimensional-array-in-php) 
and added some testing to display string for boolean value too.

It should display the json values as you wish:

```
while (!feof($resultFile)) {
    $line = fgets ($resultFile);
    //echo $line;
    $someArray = json_decode($line,true); 
    RecursiveWrite($someArray);
}

function RecursiveWrite($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        echo $key .', ';

        if(is_array($value)) {
            echo "<br>";
            RecursiveWrite($value);
        }
        elseif(is_bool($value)) {
            echo ($value? 'true' : 'false') . "<br>"; 
        }
        else {
            echo $value . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dexter0015, your answer is accepted. However facing issues with multiple lines from API. Do you want me to open separate question to avoid mess here? What do you suggest?

Comment: Hi @JiteshSojitra, yes please.

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54532369/extract-key-value-pair-output-from-json-file-using-php

Answer (score 1):

How about that `$someArray = json_decode($line,true);`? because without the 2nd parameter `true`, `json_decode()` will return results as `object` and for that case you've to use `$value->key` while accessing keys not `$value['key']`

```
while (!feof($resultFile)) {
    $line = fgets ($resultFile);
    echo $line;
    $someArray = json_decode($line,true); # see the tweak here
    foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {
        echo $value["key"] . ", " . $value["status"] . "<br/>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but it is printing as per screenshot added in the post unfortunately with single characters.

Answer (score 1):

First I agree with Dexter0015's answer. It should be marked as the correct answer as it will deal with a wide variety of results.

I just thought I'd throw my two cents in for a shorter and very problem specific to the user's issue.

```
/* Load up a record that is json encoded */
$json = '{"key":"XYZ-6680","status":"Open","components":"API","currentVersion":"Release1.2","expectedVersion":[],"customerInfo":"Default Calendar when the delegate responds to those invitations."}';
/* Use json_decode to convert the JSON string to a PHP Array. Be sure and set the second parameter to true in json_decode to get an array and not an object */
$array = json_decode($json, true);

/*
 * Now iterate through the result extracting the key and value of the array created from json decode 
 * There could be instances (expectedVersion) that may have an array of values. So test to see
 * if the array value is an array. If so using print_r, otherwise just echo out the $value as a string
 */
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (!is_array($value)) {
        echo '* Key ' . $key . ' has a value of :' . $value . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "* Key " . $key . ' has an array of values :' . print_r($value, true) . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: For more information regarding json_decode you can go here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php